# Why am I getting an Index Out Of Bounds Exception?

Tags: java, grid, indexoutofboundsexception

I am attempting to fix already written code which deals with getting a grid from a webpage. Currently the code looks like this:

```
 public static Grid getGrid(String gridXpath) {

    Grid grid = new Grid();
    String html = getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath(gridXpath)).getAttribute("outerHTML");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    String paginationType = getPaginationType(gridXpath);
    grid.setPaginationType(paginationType);

    // get headers
    Element table = doc.select("table").get(0);
    Elements headers = table.select("th");
    table = doc.select("table").get(doc.select("table").size() - 1);
    Elements bodies = table.select("tbody");
    Elements rows = bodies.select("tr");
    Elements detailRows = bodies.select("tr.k-detail-row");

    for (Element th : headers) {
        if (th.hasClass("k-header") && !th.hasClass("k-hierarchy-cell")) {
            if (th.html().contains("class=\"second-row\"")) {
                Element subHeader = th.selectFirst("span.second-row");
                grid.addSubHeader(subHeader.text());
                th.select("span.second-row").remove();
                grid.addHeader(th.text());
            } else {
                grid.addHeader(th.text());
                grid.addSubHeader(null);
            }
        } else if (!th.hasClass("k-hierarchy-cell")) {
            grid.addHeader(th.text());
            grid.addSubHeader(null);
        }
    }
    // add detail row header if it exists
    if (!detailRows.isEmpty()) {
        grid.addHeader("detail");
        grid.addSubHeader("detail");
    }

    // get rows
    for (Element tr : rows) {
        Row row = grid.new Row();
        if (tr.hasClass("k-master-row")) {
            Elements cells = tr.select("td");
            for (Element td : cells) {
                Cell cell = grid.new Cell();
                cell.addCellLocation(td.cssSelector());
                if (td.attr("role").equalsIgnoreCase("gridcell")) {
                    if (td.html().contains("onclick=")) {
                        Element button = td.selectFirst("button");
                        cell.addCellControl(button.cssSelector());
                        td.select("button").remove();
                    } else {
                        cell.addCellControl(null);
                    }
                    if (td.html().contains("span")) {
                        if (td.html().contains("class=\"second-row\"")) {
                            Element subCell = td.selectFirst("span.second-row");
                            if (subCell.text().isEmpty()) {
                                cell.setSubText(null);
                            } else {
                                cell.setSubText(subCell.text());
                            }
                            td.select("span.second-row").remove();
                            if (td.text().isEmpty()) {
                                cell.setText(null);
                            } else {
                                cell.setText(td.text());
                            }
                        } else {
                            cell.setText(td.select("span").text());
                            td.select("span").remove();
                            cell.setSubText(td.text());
                        }
                    } else {
                        cell.setText(td.text());
                        cell.setSubText(null);
                    }
                    row.addCell(cell);
                }
            }
            row.addCell(createCell(detailRows.get((grid.getRows().size())).cssSelector(), detailRows.get((grid.getRows().size())).text()));
            grid.addRow(row);
        } else if (!tr.hasClass("k-detail-row")) {
            Elements cells = tr.select("td");
            for (Element td : cells) {
                Cell cell = grid.new Cell();
                cell.addCellLocation(td.cssSelector());
                if (td.html().contains("<input")) {
                    Element input = td.selectFirst("input");
                    cell.setText(null);
                    cell.setSubText(null);
                    cell.addCellControl(input.cssSelector());

                } else {
                    cell.setText(td.text());
                    cell.setSubText(null);
                    cell.addCellControl(null);
                }
                row.addCell(cell);

                if (td.hasAttr("colspan")) {
                    for (int i = 1; i < Integer.valueOf(td.attr("colspan")); i++) {
                        row.addCell(createCell(null, null));
                    }
                }
            }
            grid.addRow(row);
        }
    }
```

This code works fine if there is only one page of data on the grid, but it falls over when there are more than one. To solve this, I have attempted to add  some pagination code. I have the following so far:

```
if (paginationType != null && getCurrentPage(gridXpath, grid.getPaginationType()) != getLastPageNumberShownInPagination(gridXpath, grid.getPaginationType())) {
        do {
            gotoNextPage(gridXpath, grid.getPaginationType());

            html = getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath(gridXpath)).getAttribute("outerHTML");
            doc = Jsoup.parse(html);


            table = doc.select("table").get(0);
            table = doc.select("table").get(doc.select("table").size() - 1);
            bodies = table.select("tbody");
            rows = bodies.select("tr");
            detailRows = bodies.select("tr.k-detail-row");

            for (Element tr : rows) {
                Row row = grid.new Row();
                if (tr.hasClass("k-master-row")) {
                    Elements cells = tr.select("td");
                    for (Element td : cells) {
                        Cell cell = grid.new Cell();
                        cell.addCellLocation(td.cssSelector());
                        if (td.attr("role").equalsIgnoreCase("gridcell")) {
                            if (td.html().contains("onclick=")) {
                                Element button = td.selectFirst("button");
                                cell.addCellControl(button.cssSelector());
                                td.select("button").remove();
                            } else {
                                cell.addCellControl(null);
                            }
                            if (td.html().contains("span")) {
                                if (td.html().contains("class=\"second-row\"")) {
                                    Element subCell = td.selectFirst("span.second-row");
                                    if (subCell.text().isEmpty()) {
                                        cell.setSubText(null);
                                    } else {
                                        cell.setSubText(subCell.text());
                                    }
                                    td.select("span.second-row").remove();
                                    if (td.text().isEmpty()) {
                                        cell.setText(null);
                                    } else {
                                        cell.setText(td.text());
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    cell.setText(td.select("span").text());
                                    td.select("span").remove();
                                    cell.setSubText(td.text());
                                }
                            } else {
                                cell.setText(td.text());
                                cell.setSubText(null);
                            }
                            row.addCell(cell);
                        }
                    }
                    row.addCell(createCell(detailRows.get((grid.getRows().size())).cssSelector(), detailRows.get((grid.getRows().size())).text()));
                    grid.addRow(row);
                } else if (!tr.hasClass("k-detail-row")) {
                    Elements cells = tr.select("td");
                    for (Element td : cells) {
                        Cell cell = grid.new Cell();
                        cell.addCellLocation(td.cssSelector());
                        if (td.html().contains("<input")) {
                            Element input = td.selectFirst("input");
                            cell.setText(null);
                            cell.setSubText(null);
                            cell.addCellControl(input.cssSelector());

                        } else {
                            cell.setText(td.text());
                            cell.setSubText(null);
                            cell.addCellControl(null);
                        }
                        row.addCell(cell);

                        if (td.hasAttr("colspan")) {
                            for (int i = 1; i < Integer.valueOf(td.attr("colspan")); i++) {
                                row.addCell(createCell(null, null));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    grid.addRow(row);
                }
            }
```

Most of this code is just a copy/paste from the previous code, but when I run it I am getting the error 'java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 10 out of bounds for length 3' from the following line:

row.addCell(createCell(detailRows.get((grid.getRows().size())).cssSelector(), detailRows.get((grid.getRows().size())).text()));

I am not sure why this line of code works before pagination but doesn't work after. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: So it turns out the issue is that the grid contains all data from the previous page, and so when I use grid.getRows().size() it is counting all rows instead of just the rows from the current page. Any suggestions on how I can use just the rows on the current page ?

Can I create a new grid and the add this to the existing grid once I have all the data ?

Comment: Have a look at `detailRows.get((grid.getRows().size())`, turn on a debugger and have a look why `detailRows.size()` is smaller than `grid.getRows().size()`.

Comment: @Glains detailRows.size() and grid.getRows().size() both have the value 10

Comment: However when I enter detailRows.get((grid.getRows().size())) into the expressions panel in debug mode I get the Index Out Of Bounds Exception for this value. Do you know why this exception would appear ?

Comment: If both have size = 10, that explains the error. Indices are 0-based. So, may be you need to change this as: `detailRows.get((grid.getRows().size() - 1))`

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the size of the `List` is not equal to the actual available `List` indexes. For a `List` with 2 elements, you would get the size of 2, but the actual elements can be received with `list.get(0)` and `list.get(1);`.

To fix you problem, simply subtract one from your list size:

```
detailRows.get((grid.getRows().size() - 1)
```

Comment: I have changed this row to be: row.addCell(createCell(detailRows.get((grid.getRows().size())).cssSelector(), detailRows.get((grid.getRows().size() -1)).text())); However now I am receiving the error - 'java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 10 out of bounds for length 10'

Comment: You have multiple statements, which call `grid.getRows().size()`. Please adapt all of them, not just one.

Comment: I have figured out why this line of code throwing the exception, please see edit above. Any suggestions on how to fix this would be appreciated.